# using ffmpeg concat on slideshow videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to build time lapse animations from still images.
The first image is repeated to create a header. Next steps is to concatenate header plus time lapse for final video. Both header and time lapse are created fine. Creating the concatenated final video does not give expected result.

ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7 on kubuntu 14.

The header

```
ffmpeg -framerate 16 -f image2 -i './Header/Sun_20150214_head_%02d.png' -vf "crop=1240:940:40:10" -vf drawtext="fontsize=100:fontcolor=yellow:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf:textfile=./scripts/header_text.txt:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 16 -y ./Video/sunspot_20150214_header.mp4

ffmpeg -i ./Video/sunspot_20150214_header.mp4 -vf fade=in:0:30 -crf 24 -y ./Video/sunspot_20150214_header_fade.mp4
```

On its own the header plays fine and has a nice fade.

Now for the time lapse:

```
ffmpeg -r 12 -threads 0 -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i './npy2reg/Sun_20150214_*.png'  -c:v libx264 -crf 16 -vf "crop=1240:940:40:10" -y ./Video/sunspot_20150214_crf16_12fps.mp4
```

On its own the time lapse plays fine.

Tried concat using a concat.txt file with pointers to both input files.
concat.txt file :

```
file '/home/gottsch/sunspot_20150214/Video/sunspot_20150214_header_fade.mp4'
file '/home/gottsch/sunspot_20150214/Video/sunspot_20150214_crf16_12fps.mp4'
```

The cmd for ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i ./scripts/concat.txt -c copy -y  ./Video/sunspot_20150214_crf16_12fps_final.mp4
```

This gives my output file `sunspot_20150214_crf16_12fps_final.mp4`.
Problem : The output file shows only the header.

I have read that ffmpeg concat engine requires the input videos to be same format which I believe is given when ffmpeg created them both.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Gert

UPDATE:

I was asked to provide console output of following cmd:

```
gottsch@ubuntu:~/sunspot_20150214$ ffmpeg -i './Header/Sun_20150214_head_%02d.png' -pattern_type glob -i './npy2reg/Sun_20150214_*.png'
ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    53.  5.103 / 53.  5.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from './Header/Sun_20150214_head_%02d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:02.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1280x960, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, image2, from './npy2reg/Sun_20150214_*.png':
  Duration: 00:00:01.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1280x960, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
gottsch@ubuntu:~/sunspot_20150214$
```

following that it seems OK to process both parts in one cmd. My image processing script creates the files in enumerated format, so the second part can be written without the glob with % notation.

```
ffmpeg -i './Header/Sun_20150214_head_%02d.png' -i './npy2reg/Sun_20150214_%02d.png'
```

The cmd line error about missing output file is no problem. My concern is the series of filters I had planned to incorporate. (fade,text,crop). Is there a tutorial on proper sequencing and precedence control of the filters?

I also have concern on the broadest possible compatibility of the created mpeg so that the most combinations of devices / os / browsers can process it.

On my prev attempt I received feedback that it fails in MAC OS browser with a missing plugin error.

Thanks,
Gert

UPDATE2

Follwing lines each produce a video of the header, only. No frame from the timelapse is shown.

```
ffmpeg -i './Header/Sun_20150214_head_%02d.png' -i './npy2reg/Sun_20150214_%02d.png' -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 16 -y ./Video/sunspot_20150214_crf16_12fps_test.mp4

ffmpeg -i './Header/Sun_20150214_head_%02d.png' -pattern_type glob -i './npy2reg/Sun_20150214_*.png' -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 16 -y ./Video/sunspot_20150214_crf16_12fps_test.mp4
```

Best,
Gert

Comment: Why not do it all in one command and therefore avoid using concat? You didn't provide your console outputs so I can't give you an exact answer.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Your suggestion is fine. My abilities in ffmpeg are too limited to execute on that idea. I can give you a description of my input data and desired outcome and would greatly appreciate help in achieving it. 
I have ca. 50 png files making up a time lapse. I would like to create a video with following features. A fade from black to a still image (1st image from sequence) with descriptive title. Then start of timelapse through the 50png files. End. I would like to embed this into a web page with the goal to be readable by the most combinations of devices and browsers. Thx Gert.

Comment: Please show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i './Header/Sun_20150214_head_%02d.png' -pattern_type glob -i './npy2reg/Sun_20150214_*.png'`

Comment: Have you tried just using the linux cat command? it worked for me once, though it wasnt with 2 mp4 files...

Answer (score 2):

From what I see your videos have different framerates, 16fps and 12fps. For concatenating videos and using the concat *demuxer*, the only thing that can be different for the videos to concatenate might be the bitrate, everything else, resolution, fps, codec, color format...must be equal.

See the [FFmpeg wiki Concatenation section](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

**Possible solutions**

- Equalise all possible parameters of your videos (fps, size, ...)
- Compose your videos in GUI video editor like [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/)
- FFMpeg is rather limited for editing tasks like fades and texts. If you really want to create / compose videos programmatically, personally I'd use a frameserver like [avisynth](http://avisynth.nl/), which provides all of what you need through its [internal filters](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Internal_filters) (`ImageSource`, `FadeIn`, `Subtitle`, ...). However, it is only available for windows. There is a Linux port of it called [avxsynth](https://github.com/avxsynth/avxsynth/wiki), though I never tried that one. Using a frame server provides the possibility to preview the end
  result in a media player of your choice, super easy change of
  parameters and encoding the end result in one go.
- Use ffmpegs concat *filter* : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec. I've had mixed success with that one.

**Example avisynth script**

I made simple avisynth script `sunspot.avs` which could be a starting point for you. I tried this in windows, but in theory, it should work with avxsynth as well...

```
# Set the desired parameters for the output video
out_fps = 25
out_width = 800
out_height = 600

# Make a title clip
blank = BlankClip(length=out_fps * 3, width=out_width, height=out_height, fps=out_fps, color=$000000).KillAudio()
blank_subtitle = blank.Subtitle("Your Title", align=5, size=60, text_color=$ffff00)

# Load image sequence, assume 16 input fps 16, convert to output video's 25fps
# NOTE: since the input frame rates differs from the output frame rate, there will be interpolation going on... 
sunspot = ImageReader("Sun_20150214_%02d.png", 1, 62, 16).ChangeFPS(out_fps).ConvertToRGB32()
# Crop & Resize, pay attention not to distort the images to the ratios
sunspot_cropped = sunspot.Crop(8,2,-9,-4).LanczosResize(out_width, out_height)

# Concatenate the clips (which now have the same fps + format + color space)
blank_subtitle.FadeIn(out_fps * 1) ++ sunspot_cropped
```

You can preview the result with `ffplay sunspot.avs` and if satisfied, convert it to an mp4 file, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i sunspot.avs -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset:v slower -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac sunspot.mp4
```

Comment: @phobos. Thank you for looking at the issue. As I create both (header and time lapse) from indiv still frames I am in control of the frame rate. I can set the frame rate to same for both and try again. As a side question I'd like to know how to make the header from just 1 still. I shall post a new thread.